# Rename files in a Windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Can you please help me with my problem. I need to rename some files in a directory and must do it in a Windows batch file.
The files have the format `VXXXX__<some-name>` where `XXXX` can be any number. I need to rename the files to some-name removing the `V9999__`. I have the following but it does not work for me

```
REM Get all files from directory
for %%f in (C:\data\\*.sql) do (
   echo %%~nf     
   how to split the filename and rename the file ???
)
```

Comment: Read here how to accept an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

Use a for command, giving delimiters and token (substring) indication: the first token (%g) will be the text to the left of the underscore, and the rest of the text will be placed in %h (the next token)

**edited** to remove the non needed echo

```
for %%f in (*_*.sql) do for /f "tokens=1,* delims=_" %%g in ("%%~f") do echo ren "%%~f" "%%~h"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
for /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d U:\data\*_*.sql') do (
   echo REN U:\data\%%f_%%g %%g
)
GOTO :EOF
```

First, execute a `dir` on the directory (I've changed the drive...) of files matching `*_*.sql, in`/b`(bare) format - name only, no headers and`/ad` - no directorynames.

Read each line with a `FOR /F`, assigning the part before the `_` delimiter to `%%f` (token 1) and the remainder of the line after the delimiter (token "*") to the next metavariable (%%g)

Then do your rename - I've just `echo`ed it